# Run JS by clicking a div element

Tags: javascript, html

Im working on a website that has a few different colored boxes made with divs, and I want to use them to open certain things. Whether it be music, photos, etc. Im using JS to generate a random number and use the number to choose which song to open, but I have no clue how to attach it to the div itself.

```
</head>
<body style="background-color:#FFF;">
<div id="center">
<div id="header">
<div id="title"><h1>welcom3 :-)</h1></div>
    <div id="wrapper">
    <div id="redbox">
    </div>
    <div id="6box">
    </div>
    <div id="bluebox">
    </div>
    <div id="greenbox">
    </div>
    <div id="yellowbox">
    </div>
    <div id="yellowboxmargin">
    </div>
    <div id="yellowboxmargin">
    </div>
    <div id="yellowboxmargin">
    </div>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: onclick="call_the_function_of_your_choice" and do your stuff ...

Comment: @SomeOne Please don't recommend anyone from using `onclick`... They are [bad, bad, bad coding practice](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5871640/283863).

Comment: yeap, agree that they are bad, but, I was just trying to suggest that you could do something with click event. my bad.

Comment: Can include `html` , `css` , `js` at Question ?

Comment: In case you have checked my answer and thought that the snippet was not working, I just forgot to link the jQuery library. You can check it now.

Answer (score 2):

use jQuery

```
 <div id="box1"></div>
 <script> 
   $(document).ready(function() {
     $("#box1").click(function(){
      yourfunc();
     }
   })
 </script>
```

Comment: Does it matter where I would place this in the HTML?

Comment: no .
as the document `.ready` function makes it function after the Dom is loaded.

the html will go on the body .
and you can put the js on the head or any where you want. 

add more `.click` functions in to the `.ready` event function  if you want.

this method is really helpfull if you are using cordova / phonegap

Answer (score 2):

If you need run js code without jquery, use this example.

In head:

```
<script>
function hello() { 
    // do something
}
</script>
```

In body:

```
<div onclick="hello()">Hello</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would follow the advice of *Buddhi Abeyratne* and use jQuery. Of course, this is just a guess, but I would say that due to the nature of your project, it will make things easier for you.

jQuery has [different methods](https://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-handler-attachment/) to attach events to an alement. In this case, you can use the shortcut "[*.click()*](https://api.jquery.com/click/)".

I leave you here a snippet:

```js
function do_something_cool(box)
{
    alert("I have code to make something awesome with " + box.attr("id"));
}

$(document).ready(function()
{
    $("#wrapper div").click(function() { do_something_cool($(this)); });
});
```

```css
body 
{
  background-color: #FFF;
}

.colored_box 
{
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  margin: 5px;
}

#redbox
{
  background-color: red;
}

#bluebox
{
  background-color: blue;
}

#greenbox
{
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
  <div id="center">
    <div id="header">
      <div id="title"><h1>welcom3 :-)</h1></div>
      <div id="wrapper">
        <div id="redbox" class="colored_box"></div>
        <div id="bluebox" class="colored_box"></div>
        <div id="greenbox" class="colored_box"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

But if you decide to don't use jQuery, here you have the vanilla javascript:

```
window.onload = function()
{
  var boxes = document.getElementById("wrapper").getElementsByTagName("div");
  for (var i = 0; i < boxes.length; i++)
  {
    boxes[i].addEventListener("click", do_something_cool);
  } 
}

function do_something_cool(evt)
{
  alert("I have code to make something awesome with " + evt.target.id);
}
```

Btw, I guess it is just a copy/paste thing, but you forgot to close one *div*.

Also, pay attention to how I have separated html, js and css in the snippet. You should avoid inline js and css.

Good luck!